# Search and extract from String in R

Tags: r

I have a String: "Development Document ID Z585 Design No. PZ585A2202 Marked as"

I need to extract the alphanumeric part of the string: "PZ585A2202".
Tried :

```
p_string <- "Development Document ID Z585 Design No. PZ585A2202 Marked as"
regexp <- "(([:alnum:]))"
str_extract(p_string,regexp)
```

But obviously,I am getting this wrong. Is there a way I can identify that alphanumeric part of the string and extract it? 
Unfortunately, I wont know the position or what precedes or follows it.

Comment: Do you at least know the length of the part you want to extract? I.e. - how can one determine if the result should be Z585 or PZ585A2202?

Comment: Thanks for responding and yes, I do know the length. Sorry. Forgot to mention that in the original post. The part I need to extract is always 10 characters long. This is a system generated ID.

Comment: Beside length are there any pattern in this ID ?

Comment: Nope unfortunately, there is no set pattern to this ID.

Comment: I see you've said you won't know what precedes it - does that include 'No. '?

Comment: Building on what @alexwhan said: in order to parse the string, you'll need some identifying features.  @alexwhan suggests `No. `.  If that string ALWAYS preceeds the string you want to extract, the solution will be a bit simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing the string is exactly 10 characters which only include capital letters and numbers, you could do something like this:

```
regmatches(p_string, regexpr("([A-Z0-9]{10})", p_string))
```

You might get false positives if the strings include words of more than 10 letters in all caps, but unless you have more identifying features (as was mentioned in the comments) it seems unlikely you can do better.